# How to use Python to get XMLthe contents of the elements?

Tags: python, xml, dom

I want to get `12345` through `NodeID`, using `python's DOM`.

This is XML：

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<Inventory version="2.0">
    <Component Classname="DCIM_ControllerView" Key="RAID.Slot.1-1">
       <PROPERTY NAME="NodeID" TYPE="string">
         <VALUE>20161210161621</VALUE>
         <DisplayValue>20161210161621</DisplayValue>
       </PROPERTY>
    </Component>
    <Component Classname="DCIM_SystemView" Key="System.Embedded.1">
       <PROPERTY NAME="NodeID" TYPE="string">
         <VALUE>12345</VALUE>
         <DisplayValue>12345</DisplayValue>
       </PROPERTY>
    </Component>
</Inventory>
```

Comment: Your question contains no code. This means there is no code for us to fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree
e = xml.etree.ElementTree.fromstring(theXmlString) # or from file
e.findall("Component[@Key='RAID.Slot.1-1']/PROPERTY/VALUE")[0].text
```